# Strange but simple question

Tags: linear-transformations, definition

Is there a name for the type of trick where we do something like $s=(1-p)r+pq$ where we are making a sum of complementary ratios of two numbers? This kind of reminds me of convolution but I thought there is a name for what this is doing?

Comment: Here you are taking a convex combination of $r$ and $q$.

Comment: Consider what happens when $p$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: @paulinho: the OP set no constraint on $p$.

Comment: for $p\in [0,1]$ it is a convex combination of $r$ and $q$, for $p\in\mathbb{R}$ it is a linear combination of $r$ and $q$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I assumed that since the OP was referring to ratios, $p$ and $1-p$ would both between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @paulinho: fair enough.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! I was looking for a convex combination.

Answer (score 3):

This is a *linear interpolation* between $r$ and $q$, with the parameter $t$ ($\in[0,1]$ for interpolation, otherwise extrapolation; as mentioned by others, also convex combination or linear combination). $r,q$ can be vectors. For $p=\frac12$, you get the *middle*.